# Spring mvc Controller Null Pointer Exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, testing

I'm trying to test my controller with this url mapping:

```
controller Code:  
        HttpSession sessionHttp;
        @Controller
            public class LoginController {
               @RequestMapping(value="/logout")
                 public String logout(ModelMap model) {
                  sessioneHttp.invalidate();
                  return "login-credential";  
    }}
```

---

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")

public class MainControllerTest {
 @Autowired  
   private WebApplicationContext wac;  
   private MockMvc mockMvc;  
        @InjectMocks
        private LoginController loginController= new LoginController();

     @Before public void setUp() {
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(loginController).build();
        }

        @Test
           public void LogoutTest() throws Exception {
             this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/logout"))  
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())  
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("login-credential"))
               .andDo(print());       
            }

            }
```

---

```
    And this is the stackTrace:



org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception     is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:170)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:141)
    at org.controllers.MainControllerTest.LogoutTest(MainControllerTest.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at it.sydema.laweb.controllers.LoginController.logout(LoginController.java:251)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    ... 38 more
```

*I don't know why i'm getting the null pointer exception.
Appreciate any help.*

Comment: What's the code at the following file and line? This is the root cause for the NPE:

it.sydema.laweb.controllers.LoginController.logout(LoginController.java:251)

Comment: Hi,It's the same as above , line 251 is the following :sessioneHttp.invalidate();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `HttpSession sessionHttp;` field is just class property, you have to pass it in through controller method parameters so spring mvc will inject correct session for you.

Try:

```
@Controller 
public class LoginController { 
    @RequestMapping(value="/logout") 
    public String logout(ModelMap model, HttpSession session){
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,freakman, for the quick answer.it works.Is there a method or some modifications can i add to my LogoutTest method to have informations about the session?

Comment: dont know at the moment how to get session values in tests, but if you need to pass some then use .sessionAttr() method after get(). Please accept answer if your primary question is answered :)